# Compare two columns data (if they're strings )in Python with the module pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Some of my code is un-needed, but, I have a script that takes the columns I have listed at the end and puts them after the one that has the size. It matches the sizes like 12x12 would have all of the rows that have 12x12, plus, adding every columns after it.
I need to accomplish getting the output as every line matching the sizes and add everything past that, but, once it passes that number, it moves on the next.
Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
  

data1 = pd.read_csv('artist-sheet.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('master.csv')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
orig = data2["Orig Size"]
original = data1["Original Size"]

conditions = [
    data2['Orig Size'] == data1['Original Size']]
if data2['Orig Size'].equals(data1['Original Size']):
    result = pd.merge(data1,
                 data2[['Original Size', 'Sales Price', 'Width', 'Length', 'Square Inches', 'Cost / Sq Inch,Cost']],
                 on='Orig Size')
result.head()
```

Here is the error:

```
line 12, in <module>
    data2['Orig Size'] == data1['Original Size']]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 70, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py", line 40, in __eq__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 5617, in _cmp_method
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: The conditions section is not really needed, it is just what I tried to use earlier to see if they match.

Comment: you have to join two dataframes before you can compare the columns , please provide minimal reproducibale code and sample data and show us your desired output